# Problems with "How to use a PCL tutorial in ROS"

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm new testing ubuntu, ros and PCL. Well this is my problem: I tested the tutorial of ros page, all things look good but when i write : rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/camera/depth/points nothing happen (I'm using Kinect so I changed the input). Then I used rviz to see the output and the input and I can see something, I added in rviz a camera and PointCloud2 but I'm not sure about the images that rviz shows in Camera and PointCloud2 I don't know if the image in PointCloud2 have the Voxel Filter. I hope that someone can help me, please. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83601/problems-with-%22how-to-use-a-pcl-tutorial-in-ros%22/) by [App](https://answers.ros.org/users/7091/app/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-09-26**:
Could you organize your question a little better? I don't understand what your question is. Please cite specifically what behavior you expected to happen, what behavior is being observed, and what question you want answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry. I could not view the tutorials, but I could finally use rviz and run the program that comes with this format: sensor_msgs/PointCloud2. To view we only have to add "PointCloud2" in rviz, when we select are the topics to which we can subscribe. Now I have another problem: I can not see anything if I use the format pcl / PointCloud . I run the program with rosrun my_pcl_tutorial ... open after rviz and add PointCloud2 but to see the output is supposed to appear the topic "output" is not listed yet, what is the problem?
Thanks =)

---

Originally posted by [App](https://answers.ros.org/users/7091/app/) with karma: 16 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0